# Finite sum of the Leibniz formula for $\pi/4$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Leibniz formula for $\pi/4$ is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + ... $$
How to calculate the summation of the first $n$ terms in the above series?

Comment: $\pi/4$ I think

Comment: pi/4 is the sum for i=0 to i=infinity. What is the sum for i=0 to i=n.

Comment: (What I meant of course was that the original, unedited post had the sum equal to $\pi$.)

Comment: I understand. But the unedited post did have info about finitude of the sum. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2}[\psi_0(3/2+n)-\psi_0(1/2)],$$

where $\psi_0(x)$ is the [Polygamma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) function (also known as the DiGamma function for this case). There are likely no further simplifications possible (if this even counts as one).

Comment: Proof, other than WA?

Comment: @nbubis: the proof follows immediately by telescoping the series definition of the Polygamma function in the link

Answer (score 0):

you can use the equivalent formula which is
$$1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{1*3}$$
$$\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{2}{5*7}$$
and so on to get 
$$S=2(\frac{1}{1*3}+\frac{1}{5*7}+\frac{1}{9*11}+\frac{1}{13*15}+.....)$$

Comment: The motive behind the question is to reduce dramatically the effort required in calculating the sum for large n. Here, although the number of terms has reduced to half, but the summation still exists.